# PHP Spintax return array with all possibilities

Tags: php, spintax

I have a string: `{Hello|Howdy|Hola} to you, {Mr.|Mrs.|Ms.} {Smith|Williams|Austin}`!

I wonder if someone can help me out with a function that will return an array with all the possibilities ? Or at least provide the logic on how to get them and what PHP functions to use ?

Thank you

Comment: I am sure `var_dump` or `print_r` would give you the desired array, unless I have completely misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested `foreach` loops.

```
foreach($greetings as greeting)
    foreach($titles as title)
        foreach($names as $name)
            echo $greeting,' to you, ',$title,' ',$name;
```

You can adjust the order that they appear by sorting the arrays beforehand and by changing the order on the first three lines

**UPDATE**

This is what I came up with using a recursive function

It assumes you have your data in something like this using regular expressions and explode this should be pretty trivial to get to:

```
$data = array(
    array("Hello","Howdy","Hola"),
    array(" to you, "),
    array("Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms."),
    array(" "),
    array("Smith","Williams","Austin"),
    array("!")
);
```

Now here is the function

```
function permute(&$arr, &$res, $cur = "", $n = 0){

    if ($n == count($arr)){
        // we are past the end of the array... push the results
        $res[] = $cur;
    } else {
                    //permute one level down the array
        foreach($arr[$n] as $term){
            permute($arr, $res, $cur.$term, $n+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example invocation:

```
$ret = array();
permute($data, $ret);
print_r($ret);
```

Which yields the output

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Hello to you, Mr. Smith!
    [1] => Hello to you, Mr. Williams!
    [2] => Hello to you, Mr. Austin!
    [3] => Hello to you, Mrs. Smith!
    [4] => Hello to you, Mrs. Williams!
    [5] => Hello to you, Mrs. Austin!
    [6] => Hello to you, Ms. Smith!
    [7] => Hello to you, Ms. Williams!
    [8] => Hello to you, Ms. Austin!
    [9] => Howdy to you, Mr. Smith!
    [10] => Howdy to you, Mr. Williams!
    [11] => Howdy to you, Mr. Austin!
    [12] => Howdy to you, Mrs. Smith!
    [13] => Howdy to you, Mrs. Williams!
    [14] => Howdy to you, Mrs. Austin!
    [15] => Howdy to you, Ms. Smith!
    [16] => Howdy to you, Ms. Williams!
    [17] => Howdy to you, Ms. Austin!
    [18] => Hola to you, Mr. Smith!
    [19] => Hola to you, Mr. Williams!
    [20] => Hola to you, Mr. Austin!
    [21] => Hola to you, Mrs. Smith!
    [22] => Hola to you, Mrs. Williams!
    [23] => Hola to you, Mrs. Austin!
    [24] => Hola to you, Ms. Smith!
    [25] => Hola to you, Ms. Williams!
    [26] => Hola to you, Ms. Austin!
)
```

Comment: Thanks Orangepill, but that's limited. And i won't even have a clue on how many combinations of { | } i will get. Can be 10, 100 :)

Comment: From what i could read over the internet, i'll probably need some permutations. I've found a couple of good permutation functions, don't just know how to combine them with that string

Comment: @raul - All the possibilities? What you posted looks like article spinning. In that case, you don't need all the possibilities. You just need to randomly select an item within each set of brackets.

Comment: Yes, it's like article spinning. But i want all the possibilities. The project is a bit different. I have the spinning class, works just fine. I just don't know how to write or change stuff to give me the array with all, instead of 1 random line.

Comment: ah, maybe to mention that i don't really care about NESTED one, like { hello {x|y}, how are you|good day {x|y} !} I just care about that 1 level actually:)

Comment: OrangePill, yes, that looks great. And yes, i can split the initial string and make that first array.

Comment: I don't think this can handle nested spintax does it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but if you are still looking for a better solution, you can take a look at this: [ChillDevSpintax](https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/ChillDevSpintax/blob/develop/Resources/doc/usage.md#dumping-all-possible-variations).